# Reading from file in c++ ifstream

Tags: c++, oop, while-loop, ifstream

I am working on a program that reads from a file and pushes back the contents of that file into a vector. It will read until the file reaches a space and push that string into a vector, then continue after the space. I have written this code.

```
  ifstream inFile;
            inFile.open("message1.txt");
            if (inFile.fail()) {
                    cerr << "Could not find file" << endl;
            }
            while (inFile >> S) {
                    code1.push_back(S);
            }
```

I am just confused about the while (inFile >> S) actually does. I understand that it reads from the inFile until it reaches the end of file. But what does the inFile >> S condition actually do? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the `inFile >> S` does is take in the file stream, which is the data in you file, and uses a space delimiter (breaks it up by whitespace) and puts the contents in the variable S.

For example:

If we had a file that had the follow contents

```
the dog went running
```

and we used `inFile >> S` with our file:

```
ifstream inFile("doginfo.txt")
string words;
while(inFile >> words) {
   cout << words << endl;
}
```

we will get the following output:

```
the
dog
went
running
```

The `inFile >> S` will continue to return true until there are no more items separated by whitespace.

Comment: is inFile.Open the same as inFile("fname.txt")?

Answer (score 3):

The expression `inFile >> S` reads a value into `S` and **will return `inFile`**.

This allows you to chain variables together like `infile >> a >> b >> c;`

Since this `inFile` is being used in a *bool context*, it will be converted to `bool`.  And `iostream` objects are defined to convert to a bool that's `true` if and only if the object has no current error state.